Is it possible to keep zeros after comma for a zero result in PSQL?
I want to keep one or two zeros after the comma when my result is equal to zero, but i see that by default they are removed for numeric type.
is there a way to add them by default for a select like that ?
SELECT
 ROUND(#myCalculation, 1)  <-- i want "0.0" if the result is zero
    END AS pourcentage_residents
FROM ...

I heard  that i can do that with " to_char(value::numeric, '0.00') " but i will need to add a case when ...

Well, this is a number, and 123 is the same as 123.0 and the same as 123.00000, so what is your problem actually? You can probably display the numeric value in any format you wish in your GUI (app or website).

WITH test(x) AS (VALUES (0.0), (0.35135), (1.6583))
SELECT round(x,1)
FROM test
